# How to choose a secondary ancestor or even tertiary ancestor in sass?

Tags: css, sass

Here is my html code

```
<body>
    <div>

        <li class="more">hello
            <ul class="hello">
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
            </ul>
        </li>


    </div>

</body>
```

and i want to generate some  css like this

```
.hello { display: none; }

.more:hover .hello { display: block; }
```

my scss

```
.more{

    .hello{
        display: none;
    }
    
    &:hover .hello{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to be more concise instead of  the selector
`&:hover .hello{} ?`

Comment: No, this is as concise as it gets. Your code looks fine to me. But I'm not sure what the title of your question means and don't know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `@at-root` rule could be used for this purpose.

> The @at-root rule is usually written @at-root  { ... } and
> causes everything within it to be emitted at the root of the document
> instead of using the normal nesting. It's most often used when doing
> advanced nesting with the SassScript parent selector and selector
> functions.

More information: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/at-root

```
.more{
    @at-root .hello{
        display: none;
    }
    
    &:hover .hello{
        display: block;
    }
}
```